# How to get Aurelia validations work?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I started with http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/validation/latest/validation-basics/1

Then tried http://blog.durandal.io/2016/06/14/new-validation-alpha-is-here/

However, validation does not happen on blur as expected. Even if I call validate on controller, errors are not set.

**login.ts**

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {ValidationController} from 'aurelia-validation';
import {ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validatejs'

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class Login {
    email:string;
    password:string;
    controller = null;

    constructor(controller){
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    submit = () => {
        this.controller.validate().then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((e) =>console.log(e));
    };
}

ValidationRules
    .ensure('email').required()
    .on(Login);
```

**login.html**

```
<form submit.delegate="submit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="control-label required">Email</label>
                    <input class="form-control" value.bind="email & validate" type="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="control-label required">Password</label>
                    <input class="form-control" value.bind="password & validate" type="password"
                           id="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="remember_me" name="remember_me" type="checkbox" value="1">
                    <label for="remember_me" class="control-label">Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**aurelia.json**

```
      {
        "name": "aurelia-validation",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-validation/dist/amd",
        "main": "aurelia-validation"
      },
      {
        "name": "validate.js",
        "path": "../node_modules/validate.js",
        "main": "validate"
      },
      {
        "name": "aurelia-validatejs",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-validatejs/dist/amd",
        "main": "aurelia-validatejs"
      },
```

**main.ts**

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-validation')
    .plugin('aurelia-validatejs')
    .feature('resources');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 0.12 `aurelia-validation` does not depend on `validate.js` anymore. Looks like you are still using `ValidationRules` from a dropped dependency. Simply change

```
import {ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validatejs'
```

to

```
import {ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validation'
```

By the way: You can completely remove `aurelia-validatejs` and `validatejs` from your project dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the validation rules inside your class, probably in the `attached` method, and you want to pass `this` instead of `Login`. It should look like this:

```
attached(){
   ValidationRules
    .ensure('email').required()
    .on(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put together an article explaining all the things you need to do for aurelia to get validation working properly. Looks like you are missing the rendering piece of the puzzle. Let me know if this clarifies things:

http://www.todroid.com/understanding-how-to-use-aurelias-validation-library/